# Looking for what seems to be an 80s hero sci fi film

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

I watched this film a while ago about a guy who was a sort of self identified super hero and he was working as an agent for earth. He infiltrates a space ship or a space station which is controlled by the villain, but there he meets his ex wife ( who looks like Samus from Metroid) who is also part of an evil plot against earth. He is aided by this geeky young scientist guy who ends up betraying him. 
What else I remember is that at one point, the hero's commander infiltrates the ship but is captured and killed by the villain when the hero refuses to surrender and that at various points he eats a "Hero sandwich".

Anybody have any idea what this film might be? I think the actors were speaking English, but my mind could be playing tricks on me, so it might be an Italian film as well. It seemed like it was made in the 80s or the early 90s.